# Background behind li element

Tags: html, css

I have an (expandable by js) list in the format of:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="title">blah</span>
        <ul>
             <li>
                <span class="arrow"></span>
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="title">blah</span>
                <ul>
                    ...
                </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="title">blah</span>
        <ul>
    ...
</ul>
```

Giving a typical layout of:

```
 - X blah
    - X blah
       . X blah
       - X blah
         . X blah
         . X blah
    - X blah
       . X blah
       . X blah
       . X blah
    + X blah
- X blah
    - X blah
```

I would like to highlight individual `<li>`'s by setting background for one or more items.
In order or apart. Is there some way to get it to fill the whole "line"?

Say for example blah 2 is selected I would like:

```
 |===================| <- this range
 - blah 1
     + blah 2
     |===============| <- not this
```

As I get by:

```
.selected {
    background : url('./img/selected.png') repeat-x;
}
```

I have tried fiddling around with margins etc. but can't get it to render the way I'd like.

Any ideas?

***EDIT:***

E.g. like the selected row under *"Groups & Items"* here.

[image]
[image: bg_slected_tree]

***EDIT2:***

Fiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/zEShd/3/

Comment: can you give a pictorial representation of what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Is [>>this fiddle<<](http://jsfiddle.net/5vgz2/) what you are trying to achieve?

Here is sample html:

```
<ul class="level1">
    <li>level 1</li>
    <li>level 1
        <ul class="level2">
            <li>level 2</li>
            <li>level 2</li>
            <li>level 2
                <ul class="level3">
                    <li>level 3</li>
                    <li>level 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and here is sample css:

```
body
{
    margin:0;
}
ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
ul.level1 > li
{
    background-color:#ffff00;
}
ul.level2 > li
{
    background-color:#ff0000;
    padding-left:20px;
}
ul.level3 > li
{
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding-left:40px;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
```

here is a second [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/yJb9j/) that works by highlighting on click.

I do it by creating absolute positioned div behind the clicked `li` element.

Comment: Yes. Something in that direction. But preferably without the fixed level margin/padding for each level as that would give n more levels of complexity to the code including javascript dynamic adding of elements etc.

Comment: @Zimzalabim here is an updated version. I hope that this does what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think that he want something like this selector `[class^="level"] {margin-left: 10px;}`. That will set left margin on all elements which have class who begins with "level". Because he want to target all levels, no matter how many levels is there.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović i agree with you, that's why i created the [2nd fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/yJb9j/), so i interact with the `li` elements but i don't modify their default margin values. The first sample was just so ill understand better what he is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a live example, it is difficult to know exactly what is going on, but this is probably due to most browser's default behavior of adding padding to nested `ul` elements.

try:

**CSS**

```
ul ul {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

Or (better) use [Eric Meyer's CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to remove these defaults. Or make them "sensible" [Normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: Thanks. But I am using normalizing routines with no help.